# WCF - StreamedResponse - minimal latency

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, streaming

I'm trying to stream live data using WCF streaming between SilverLight 5 application and .NET 4 server. What I need is minimal latency between the server and the client. However, it looks like WCF is buffering data before sending it. I'm following the example from this site: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/07/08/using-transfermode-streamedresponse-to-download-files-in-silverlight-4.aspx. I've implemented custom stream and I see that I get e.g. 10 reads of small chunks (less than 400 bytes) during one second but on the wire the server returns data every 10 seconds (it returns 32776 bytes - that's the number I get from Wireshark). I want the server to return data as soon as it is ready or at least set the buffer to very small value e.g. 512 bytes.

I tried to change client and server configuration but with no luck. My configuration looks like this:

Client

```
<client>
    <endpoint address=""
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IWcfDownloadService_StreamedResponse"
          contract="IWcfDownloadService" name="CustomBinding_IWcfDownloadService_StreamedResponse" />
</client>

<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding_IWcfDownloadService_StreamedResponse">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="StreamedResponse" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Server

```
<services>
  <service name="WcfDownloadService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="customBinding0" contract="IWcfDownloadService" />        
  </service>
</service>

<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="customBinding0">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpTransport transferMode="StreamedResponse" />          
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: You cannot use TCP tranport?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I need to tunnel the data over http.